# Show that $x_0^2 \lt 2$ is impossible by showing that if $x_0^2 \lt 2$, then there is a positive integer $n$ for which $(x_0 + \frac{1}{n})^2 \lt 2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, upper-lower-bounds

The set $S$ of rational numbers $x$ with $x^2 \lt 2$ has rational upper bounds but no least rational upper bound. Suppose that S has a least rational upper bound and call it $x_0$.

Show that $x_0^2 \lt 2$ is impossible by showing that if  $x_0^2 \lt 2$, then there is a positive integer $n$ for which $(x_0 + \frac{1}{n})^2 \lt 2$. This places $x_0 + \frac{1}{n}$ in S and shows that $x_0$ cannot be an upper bound for $S$.

---

Apologies for asking such a simple question, but I don't follow the problem posed by the question there could be a "a positive integer $n$ for which $(x_0 + \frac{1}{n})^2 \lt 2$"

Why is this problematic? Where is $n$ coming from? Is this because $x_0$ is defined to be the least rational upper bound and adding any number to it would contradict $x_0$ being the least rational upper bound?

I still don't quite see why that strictly contradicts. Or why $n$ matters... Can someone clarify the question for me? I'm obviously misunderstanding something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are trying to prove that there is no rational least upper bound.  This part proves that there cannot be a least upper bound $x_0$ with $x_0^2 \lt 2$.  There will be another part to prove there cannot be a least upper bound $x_1$ with $x_1^2 \gt 2.$  Finally, you will prove there is no rational $x_2$ with $x_2^2=2$.

We want to show there is a rational in $S$ that is greater than $x_0$, which means $x_0$ is not an upper bound at all.  If $x_0^2 \lt 2, \text{ then }x_0 \lt \sqrt 2$ by some amount.  You need to choose an $n$ large enough that $x_0+\frac 1n$ is still less than $\sqrt 2$.  That means $x_0+\frac 1n$ is in $S$, so $x_0$ is not an upper bound for $S$

If you were working in the reals, you could just let $y=\sqrt 2 -x_0$ and choose $n$ to be an integer greater than $\frac 1y$.  Here we don't have $\sqrt 2$ so you need to find a rational between $x_0$ and $\sqrt 2$.  Then $n$ can be any number greater than the inverse of the difference between your new rational and $x_0$.

Answer (score 0):

If $x^2 < 2$ then there is an integer $m$ such that
$2-x^2 > 1/m$.
Since $2-x^2 = (\sqrt{2}-x)(\sqrt{2}+x)$,
$(\sqrt{2}-x)>1/(m(\sqrt{2}+x))
>1/(4m)$.

Use this to find $n$.